# Wifi not working after fresh install of ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, 14.10

Wifi not working after fresh install of ubuntu 14.10. However I am able to access internet using Ethernet.

Below information might be useful to you -

```
kartic@kartic-Vostro-2520:~$ lspci -vnn -d 14e4:
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl


kartic@kartic-Vostro-2520:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.


kartic@kartic-Vostro-2520:~$ lspci -vvnn
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
    Region 0: Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0558]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 40
    Region 0: I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at f0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

I have read couple similar question, but nothing helped me.

Comment: Not working is always a difficult description. Does network manager see your wifi, do you just see no wifi networks or are you not able to access your own wifi?
For the lspci commands adding sudo might give a bit more information (access denied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some computers have a specie of button that activate the wireless, like Fn+F8. If it does not work, try activating the drivers at the settings. (Sorry for bad English, I am Brazilian). Hope that I solved your problem =D

Comment: Initially there was driver issue. But while fixing that somehow accidentally wifi was turned off. I'm so stupid. Thanks for your help.